# Make current screen into BLUR on Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms PCL project.
I just wanted to know if there is some way to make current screen into blur screen. 
I will put something on it.

I'm using SkiaSharp 2d library for XF which works great and support blur image. 
But it's for image file to make blur.

Should I take a screenshot for current screen and put it on the top and make it blur?

Any tip will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS for blur you may try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Essentials.Controls/ 
For Android and Win there seems to be no such a straightforward functionality but one can try creating some bitmaps and blurring them.

Answer (score 1):

The Sharpnado.MaterialFrame supports blurred background:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.MaterialFrame