# Is it possible to blur the background in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried a few things, but the only way was to install and use them on github. Is there a way to simply blur in the xaml file?

for example

I want to blur the grid background. Could this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build in blur effect in Xamarin. You need an extra tool SkiaSharp or Sharpnado.
Related Question on StackOverflow:

[Make current screen into BLUR on Xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685864/make-current-screen-into-blur-on-xamarin-forms)

Another way is to create your own control:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-use-a-blurred-image-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Grid>
    <Image Source="image.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" />
    <BoxView Color="#80000000" />
    <controls:Blur BlurType="Gaussian" BlurAmount="12" />
        ----> Rest of your code here <----
</Grid>
```

Comment: What exactly is <controls:Blur>?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [SkiaSharp image filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/image-filters). You can refer to this document about [Blurring vector graphics and bitmaps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/image-filters#blurring-vector-graphics-and-bitmaps)

```
public static SkiaSharp.SKImageFilter CreateBlur (float sigmaX, float sigmaY,
                                                  SKImageFilter input = null,
                                                  SKImageFilter.CropRect cropRect = null);
```